# What is (...) in python scripting after (:)?

Tags: python, terminal, scripting

While writing for loop in python inside a terminal we get ... in the next line.

What is the meaning of (...) and after writing code , how to exit the for loop?

[image]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode

Comment: just click on enter key again and you're good to go.

Comment: Hit enter twice

Comment: `...` is saying the code you are writing is not complete syntactically and hence it's waiting for more input from you. To break from `for` loop use the keyword `break`

Comment: `...`    is said to be secondary prompt which denotes the `suite` or `block`. It also denotes continuation  of lines like if you use multi-line string `'''  multi line string''''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ... indicates that the terminal is waiting for your next line of code. if you press enter it will run the code

Answer (score 1):

The `...` means the interpreter is waiting for any additional lines you might provide. If you are done with that indented region, simply press Enter on an empty line in order to finalize it.